# Redux Material UI TextField - Can't get field value at all

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm utilizing Redux form and the Redux Material UI package. Normally when I run code like this, it works, but for some reason, it's not able to get the value of the `TextField`. Does anyone know what's going on here?

My `console.log` statement just comes back with `{special_instructions: undefined}`

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form/immutable';

/**
 * Components
 */
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

export class EditRequestForm extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  cancel() {
    this.props.handleCancelEdit();
  }

  onSubmit(formProps) {

    const request = {
      special_instructions: formProps.get('special_instructions'),
    };
    console.log('request', request);
  }

  render() {
    // console.log(this.props.request);
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, errors } = this.props
    let request = this.props.request;
    return (
      <form className="page-form__wrapper page-body__wrapper read-request-page">
          <TextField
            name="area_instructions"
            multiLine={true}
            fullWidth={true}
            id="area_instructions"
            defaultValue={request.area_instructions}
          />
          <div className="page-form__block draft-field bg-grey">
            <RaisedButton
              primary={true}
              onTouchTap={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}
              label="Update"
            />

            <RaisedButton
              secondary={true}
              onTouchTap={handleSubmit(::this.cancel)}
              label="Cancel"
            />
          </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
  };
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'editRequest',
})(connect(mapDispatchToProps)(EditRequestForm));
```

Comment: Did you have any updates with this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Have you tried passing the TextField as component for Field in redux-form. That way, there is a high possibility to throw the exact error of third party libraries in redux-form Field. Make sure TextField is not expecting any theme as required. If so, wrap your Field inside a `<MuiThemeProvider/>`(import it from `material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider`)